# List files by date modified criteria

Tags: shell, command

I want to list all files in directory with the extension `.sel`. So far I have implemented the command script:

```
dir /b /s *.sel > list.txt
```

The problem is that the listed files need to be sorted by date modification and not name criteria. Hence I want the old files to appear at the top of the list and the newest ones at the bottom. Is there any option to do that?

Comment: Is this not what the `/T` flag is for?

Comment: Are you working on DOS (or Windows at the command line)?  The `/b` and `/s` notation for options suggests you are, in which case the [tag:shell] tag is not entirely appropriate.  The tag [tag:cmd] is appropriate for the Windows CMD.EXE command processor.  The [tag:command] is rather general and not entirely appropriate either.

Comment: download "cygwin" and get a useful command interpreter.   then ls -rt sorts "reverse time" and ls -t sorts "increasing time".  take your pick

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /b /s /OD *.sel > list.txt
```

Comment: Care to elaborate a little?